# How to make GraphQL API call from java code with SSL Context and bearer token

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, graphql, graphql-java

I need to make the graphql mutation call from java code. Ended up getting different errors while trying to call the endpoint with query as below.

**Query:**

```
mutation {
  partnerDisposition {
    send(input: {
      dispositions: [{
          dispositionStatus: HIRED,
          rawDispositionStatus: "Hired",
          rawDispositionDetails: "",
          identifiedBy: {
            ApplyID: "12345",
          },
          atsName: "MyATS",
          statusChangeDateTime: "2023-04-25T13:01:01.01Z",
        },
        {
          dispositionStatus: HIRED,
          rawDispositionStatus: "Hired",
          rawDispositionDetails: "",
          identifiedBy: {
            ApplyID: "12345",
          },
          atsName: "MyATS",
          statusChangeDateTime: "2023-04-25T13:01:01.01Z",
        }
      ],
    }) {
      numberGoodDispositions
      failedDispositions {
        identifiedBy {
          indeedApplyID
        }
        rationale
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Below is the java code I tried writing to make the API call but this is resulting in error

```
        //  GraphQL query
        String query = "mutation {\r\n"
                        + "  partnerDisposition {\r\n"
                        + "    send(input: {\r\n"
                        + "      dispositions: [{\r\n"
                        + "          dispositionStatus: HIRED,\r\n"
                        + "          rawDispositionStatus: \"Hired\",\r\n"
                        + "          rawDispositionDetails: \"\",\r\n"
                        + "          identifiedBy: {\r\n"
                        + "            ApplyID:\"12348\",\r\n"
                        + "          },\r\n"
                        + "          atsName: \"myATS\",\r\n"
                        + "          statusChangeDateTime: \"2023-04-25T13:01:01.01Z\",\r\n"
                        + "        },\r\n"
                        + "        {\r\n"
                        + "          dispositionStatus: HIRED,\r\n"
                        + "          rawDispositionStatus: \"Hired\",\r\n"
                        + "          rawDispositionDetails: \"\",\r\n"
                        + "          identifiedBy: {\r\n"
                        + "            ApplyID: \"12345\",\r\n"
                        + "          },\r\n"
                        + "          atsName: \"myATS\",\r\n"
                        + "          statusChangeDateTime: \"2023-04-25T13:01:01.01Z\",\r\n"
                        + "        }\r\n"
                        + "      ],\r\n"
                        + "    }) {\r\n"
                        + "      numberGoodDispositions\r\n"
                        + "      failedDispositions {\r\n"
                        + "        identifiedBy {\r\n"
                        + "          ApplyID\r\n"
                        + "        }\r\n"
                        + "        rationale\r\n"
                        + "      }\r\n"
                        + "    }\r\n"
                        + "  }\r\n"
                        + "}";
        
        // GraphQL API endpoint
        String graphqlEndpoint = "graphql endpoint";

        
        // Bearer token for authentication
        String bearerToken = "token";


     // Path to your local GraphQL schema file
        String schemaFilePath = "path to file";
        
     // Load the GraphQL schema from the file
        String schemaContent = loadSchemaFromFile(schemaFilePath);

        // Build the GraphQL instance with the fetched schema
        GraphQL graphQL = buildGraphQL(schemaContent);

        // Execute GraphQL query against the API endpoint with Bearer token
        ExecutionResult executionResult = executeGraphQLQuery(graphQL, query, graphqlEndpoint, bearerToken);


        // Handle the result
        if (!executionResult.getErrors().isEmpty()) {
            System.err.println("GraphQL Errors: " + executionResult.getErrors());
        } else {
            System.out.println(executionResult.getData().toString());
        }
    }

private static ExecutionResult executeGraphQLQuery(GraphQL graphQL, String query, String endpoint, String bearerToken) throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {
        try {
            SSLContext sslContext = null;
            sslContext = SSLContexts.custom().loadTrustMaterial(new TrustStrategy() {
                public boolean isTrusted(final X509Certificate[] chain, final String authType)
                        throws CertificateException {
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                    .sslContext(sslContext)
                    .build();

            HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                    .uri(URI.create(endpoint))
                    .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .header("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken)
                    .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString("{\"query\":\"" + query + "\"}"))
                    .build();
         
            return graphQL.execute(ExecutionInput.newExecutionInput().query(query).context(httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString()).body()).build());
           
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error executing GraphQL query: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
       // return null;
    }


    private static GraphQL buildGraphQL(String schemaContent) {
        TypeDefinitionRegistry typeDefinitionRegistry = new SchemaParser().parse(schemaContent);
        RuntimeWiring runtimeWiring = buildRuntimeWiring();
        GraphQLSchema graphQLSchema = new SchemaGenerator().makeExecutableSchema(typeDefinitionRegistry, runtimeWiring);

        return GraphQL.newGraphQL(graphQLSchema)
                .queryExecutionStrategy(new AsyncExecutionStrategy())
                .build();
    }
    
    private static RuntimeWiring buildRuntimeWiring() {
        return RuntimeWiring.newRuntimeWiring()
                .scalar(ExtendedScalars.DateTime)
                .scalar(emailAddressScalar())
                .scalar(phoneNumberScalar())
                .build();
    }
    
    private static GraphQLScalarType emailAddressScalar() {
        return GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
                .name("EmailAddress")
                .description("A custom scalar representing an email address")
                .coercing(new Coercing<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String serialize(Object dataFetcherResult) {
                        return String.valueOf(dataFetcherResult);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String parseValue(Object input) {
                        return String.valueOf(input);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String parseLiteral(Object input) {
                        if (input instanceof StringValue) {
                            return ((StringValue) input).getValue();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }

    private static GraphQLScalarType phoneNumberScalar() {
        return GraphQLScalarType.newScalar()
                .name("PhoneNumber")
                .description("A custom scalar representing a phone number")
                .coercing(new Coercing<String, String>() {
                    @Override
                    public String serialize(Object dataFetcherResult) {
                        return String.valueOf(dataFetcherResult);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String parseValue(Object input) {
                        return String.valueOf(input);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public String parseLiteral(Object input) {
                        if (input instanceof StringValue) {
                            return ((StringValue) input).getValue();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                })
                .build();
    }



    
    private static String loadSchemaFromFile(String filePath) {
        try {
            return new String(java.nio.file.Files.readAllBytes(new File(filePath).toPath()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Error loading GraphQL schema from file: " + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
    }
```

I override those scalars method due to some of the scalars defined in schema file.

Below is the error I am getting while running this code, seems I am not able to pass the bearer token properly to the graphql API. I need to invoke this API with bearer token and having the SSL context. I am able to make the call from postman successfully.

Error

```
GraphQL Errors: [NonNullableFieldWasNullError{message='The field at path '/partnerDisposition' was declared as a non null type, but the code involved in retrieving data has wrongly returned a null value.  The graphql specification requires that the parent field be set to null, or if that is non nullable that it bubble up null to its parent and so on. The non-nullable type is 'PartnerDispositionMutations' within parent type 'Mutation'', path=[partnerDisposition]}]
```

I am using below maven dependency for the graphql libraries.

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>
                com.graphql-java</groupId>
            <artifactId>graphql-java</artifactId>
            <version>17.4</version>
        </dependency>
```